# OpenWeather API UV Index

Tags: javascript, html, api

Using OpenWeather API, I need to find the UV Index using latitude and longitude. I need to figure out how to get the information from the queryURL request to be able to display the value on my html file.

I know my code is missing something, just not sure what it is. Right now I am using a "forecast" queryURL and see the Lat/Lon of the city I want to search, I just need to use that information to create another request. When I run my code I get the following error: "response.city.coord is not a function". This is the code I have so far:

```
    var lat = "response.city.coord"("lat");
    var lon = "response.city.coord"("lon");

    var apiKey1 = "ada1f715672a438e9b9acaa7ea0e930b";
    var queryURL2 = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/uvi?appid=${apiKey1}&lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}`;

    $.ajax({
        url: queryURL2,
        method: "GET",
    }).then(function (res) {
        var uvI = res.value;
        $(".uvIndex").text("UV Index: " + uvI);
    });
```

Comment: Is response an object?

Comment: response is an array returning from the API

Comment: Then you are accessing it the wrong way

Comment: Can you show me the structure of response?

Comment: I have updated the answer assuming that the response is an object. If you can update the question with the proper structure of response, I can give you a better answer

Comment: {cod: "200", message: 0, cnt: 40, list: Array(40), city: {…}}
city:
coord: {lat: 34.0522, lon: -118.2437}
country: "US"
id: 5368361
name: "Los Angeles"
population: 3792621
sunrise: 1591706475
sunset: 1591758222
timezone: -25200
__proto__: Object
cnt: 40
cod: "200"
list: (40) []
message: 0
__proto__: Object

Comment: Can you share the api url for this response?

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing `response` is an object like this.

```
{
  city: {
    coord: {
      lat: "some lat",
      lon: "some lon"
    }
  }
}
```

If that is the case, the way you try to access the `lat` and `lon` are wrong. It should  be accessed as follows

```
var lat = response.city.coord.lat;
var lon = response.city.coord.lon;
```

Comment: Ok, let me make those changes and see how it goes. Thanks.

Comment: If this doesn't work, Can you just share the api url you are using?